# Regex in Visual Studio Comunity

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I'm trying to replace a code using Regex in visual studio community, but I'm not getting it.

```
ZeroMemory(&ab,15);

ZeroMemory(&abc,30);

ZeroMemory(&tickt,sizeof(tickt));
```

To replace

```
memset(&ab,0,15);

memset(&abc,0,30);

memset(&tickt,0,sizeof(tickt));
```

I need to replace zeromemory with memset and the first one with ,0,
thank you all in advance

Comment: Consider creating a clang-tidy check for this. Not only is it more robust, being based on the AST instead of text, but it's also something that you can carry into the future to prevent new uses of `ZeroMemory` from popping up. It's also worth noting that zeroing memory like this isn't usually beneficial over value-initializing the object (or assigning a value-initialized object to this one) and is straight dangerous if the type has/gains invariants.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are asking about the "Find and Replace" feature in Visual Studio.

As a starting point, something like this should do what you want:

- From: `ZeroMemory\s*\((.*),`
- To: `memset($1, 0,`

Because parentheses are used in regular expressions for matching groups, you need to escape them (`\(`) if you want to match an actual parenthesis.

Then we use `(.*)` to create a group that captures whatever your first parameter is.  Note that this is very naive.  If you have a non-trivial expression for that argument (*e.g.* a function call where a comma appears anywhere) this will likely fail.

So that matches the stuff you want, and then for the replacement you can use `$1` to substitute the first matching group (in which we captured your first argument).

The only extra detail I added was a `\s*` between the function identifier and the parenthesis.  This matches optional whitespace characters, so it will still match even if you have stuff like:

```
ZeroMemory   (foo, bar);
```

I recommend you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio) to familiarize yourself with regular expressions in Visual Studio.